# How do I select a specific value in column A when grouping by column B

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have the following SQL table

```
ColA   ColB
p1     0
p1     1
p1     1
p2     0
p2     2
p3     3
p3     3
```

How can I group them by ColA and choose a specific value from ColB based on some logic.

If the corresponding ColB values for the group in ColA doesnt have any 2 then return "Pending".

If the corresponding ColB values for the group in ColA has at least a 2 then return "Active".

If the corresponding ColB values for the group in ColA are all 3 then return "Canceled".

The result for the example would be

```
ColA   Result
p1     Pending
p2     Active
p3     Cancelled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logically tricky bit is understanding when ALL colb = 3. You can do this by summing the values and dividing by 3 and comparing to the number of rows

```
select t.cola,
        case 
            when sum(case when t.colb = 2 then 1 end) > 0 then 'active' 
            when sum(case when t.colb = 3 then 3 end ) / 3 = count(*) then 'cancelled' 
        else 'pending'
        end result
from t 
group by t.cola
```